# How to get different DBAL Connection in Symfony2 Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two connection in my config.yml file

```
doctrine:
      dbal:
         default:
         connection2
```

Then in my class , i use this

`$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();`

But it is getting the default connection. How can i use the second Connection

Is it possible that i can use it from service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define both a DBAL connection and an entity manager in the config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   connection1
        connections:
            connection1:
                ...
            connection2:
                ...
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: em1
        entity_managers:
            em1:
                 connection: connection1
                 ....
            em2:
                 connection: connection2
```

No you can access the Entity mangager with:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
// Returns $em1/connection1

$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('em1');
// Returns $em1/connection1

$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('em2');
// Returns $em2/connection2
```

Comment: thanks for reply , can i pass that in my service.yml so that i can straight use $em. I want to know which  argument to pass to constructor in what code to write in constructor so that i don't need to explicitly get the connection in file