# Doctrine see only one connection config, but i declared 2 in config.yml

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my config i declare 2 connections:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: pay
        connections:
            pay:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            mein:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     somehost
                port:     3306
                dbname:   dbname
                user:     dbuser
                password: dbpassword
                charset:  UTF8
```

getEntityManager() without any paramenerts works fine, but if i will use 'pay' or 'mein', doctrine show error "EntityManager with name %name% does not exists."

Modify Registry.php

```
public function getEntityManager($name = null)
    {

        var_dump($this->entityManagers);die;
```

return

```
array(1) { ["default"]=> string(35) "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" }
```

Why it doesn't see actual config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is only the DBAL connection definition. You need to define two Entity managers too. [Please take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945213/how-to-get-different-dbal-connection-in-symfony2-doctrine2/11947663#11947663)

Comment: Ok, got it! But auto_mapping must be set to false, and i got an error "MappingException: Class Telnet\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin is not a valid entity or mapped super class.". What can i do with this error?